# Convert bootstrap snippets to semantic ui - possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I'm not that good with Frontend development and tried my Semantic-UI for the first time yesterday.
It feels nice but I'm really missing all those handy snippets sites which exist for boostrap (even templates are really rare for semantic-ui). Seems like semantic-ui isn't that popular at all and people don't provide any snippets at all.

I therefore wanted to know if it would be possible to convert all those bootstrap snippets into semantic-ui ones using a script or whatsoever. The general layout seems pretty similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *could*, ***somehow***.

**BUT** that would take extended knowledge of both Bootstrap and Semantic-UI as they have different markup and css class names, which is probably not woth fiddling around with. You'd have to write a extremely complex script that "converts" Bootstrap to Semantic-UI. You're better off recreating them manually.

In fact, here exists [an attempt](http://ehkoo.github.io/semantic-ui-examples/) of converting major bootstrap components to the Semantic-ui theme, which could spare you a lot of time.

Also there are [a lot of component examples](http://semantic-ui.com/usage/layout.html), with these you can easily build your web page - just as easy as with bootstrap components.

Comment: thanks .. already thought it's maybe too complicated. The provided links are okay, but can't compare to sites for bootstrap like bootsnip & co. Maybe it's easier to stick with bootstrap instead of semantic-ui

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is the most popular framework for responsive websites there is, semantic's vanilla theme looks really good too, i could not find a Bootstrap style that imitates exactly the style of Semantic. Thing is, Semantic is another standalone framework, it would be possible to copy all looks from Semantic to Bootstrap, but that would require some work.